# WooCommerce: Populate [product_page id="X"] where X is a URL parameter

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I have written the following code with the goal of dynamically populating the woocommerce shortcode [product_page id="X"] with a url parameter where X is the product id, with a fallback default (product ID=46) if no parameter exists in the url.

For example:

example.com/somepage?ppid=60 would change the shortcode to [product_page id="60"]

whereas

example.com/somepage would change the shortcode to [product_page id="46"] where 46 is the "default"

However, it is currently not returning the correct product page. Oddly, no matter what I try, it defaults to product ID 440 (which is the highest product ID in my db).

```
function ppid_from_query($atts) {
      $atts = shortcode_atts(array('default' => 46), $atts, 'myppid');
      $pp_id = $atts['default'];
      if (isset($_REQUEST['ppid']) && !empty($_REQUEST['ppid'])) {
        $pp_id = intval($_REQUEST['ppid']);
      }
      if (!empty($pp_id) && 46 != $pp_id) {
        return do_shortcode("[product_page id='{$ppid}']");
      }
    }
 add_shortcode('myppid', 'ppid_from_query');
```

And shortcode is added to page like [myppid default=46"]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the wrong variable `$ppid` instead of `$pp_id`. try below code.

```
function ppid_from_query( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'default' => 46
    ), $atts, 'myppid' );

    $pp_id = $atts['default'];
    
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['ppid'] ) && $_REQUEST['ppid'] != '' ) {
        $pp_id = intval( $_REQUEST['ppid'] );
    }

    return do_shortcode( "[product_page id='".$pp_id."']" );
    
}
add_shortcode( 'myppid', 'ppid_from_query' );
```